# How to use the `createServerContext` function in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

In my Next.js application, I have a page for a blogpost located at `/posts/[id]`, so it receives the `id` url segment as a param. I need to fetch the post based on this id and pass it down to a deep server component child.

I know I could use the react context api, but that would mean I'd have to make my child component a client component. However, I noticed that react exports a function called `createServerContext`. I think it might be the equivalent of `createContext` for server components.

Is this true? How can I use it? I couldn't find almost any information on this topic.

Here's what I want to be able to do:

**/posts/[id]/page.tsx**

```js
export default async function Post({ params: { id: postId } }: { params: { id: string }}) {
  const post = await getPost(postId);
  return (
    <PostContext.Provider value={{ post }}>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <ChildComponent />
    </PostContext.Provider>
  )
}

function ChildComponent() {
  const { post } = getPostContext();  
  return (
    <div>{post.createdAt}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried passing data using the normal react context (client components) and by passing it as props (server components) and the reduction in bundle size was only around *one kilobyte*! So I guess it's not a big deal to just use react context and not worry about it

Comment: I meant 2 kilobytes. From 92.4 kB to 90.5 kB